# Zoom/focus on a region/part of file in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Let's say I have a giant markdown file and want to edit one section, or a giant python file and want to edit one function. Is there any way to bring out that region of the file into a separate editor?

Desiderata:

- Find (`⌘F`) and "add selection to next find match" (`⌘D`) should only go over focused contents.
- Changes should appear in original file in the filesystem for version control purposes.
- No text outside of focused section is visible anywhere.

Bad solutions:

- 'Fold all & unfold one' works ok in markdown, but e.g. if there is section text at a parent section, then there is no way to hide it. And `⌘F` goes outside of it.
- A temp file clutters the git logs if I commit as I go.

Extension keywords (no results):

- File window
- File region
- Zoom to part of file

(Iterm2 has a feature like this for focusing on the last command output.)

Comment: What does "bring out that region of the file" mean? Or do you mean "Fold All" and then expand only the folded region you want to edit?

Comment: Updated question to be more clear

Comment: I don't believe VS Code can do what you want in the way you prefer. (It would be nice, but unfortunately, wishful thinking does not cause features to spring into existence.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there is no good solution as of May 2021.